# Как задействовать дискретную видеокарту на ноутбуке

Tags: linux, gpu, radeon

Имеется ноутбук с OS `Linux Xubuntu 18.04` и 2 видеокартами:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
```

Дискретная по идее более менее игры должна тянуть, но игры "лагают". Возможно дело в драйверах? Так их нету даже на оф. сайте.

Процессор нормальный: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz`

В `Дополнительные драйвера` - пусто
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Читал чтобы задействовать дискретную нужно запустить программу с командой

К примеру запуская программу `glxgears` с помощью `DRI_PRIME=1` должен показывать высокий FPS т.к. задействуется дискретная видеокарта (на сколько я понял), но запуская я получаю результат 60 FPS как через эту команду так и без нее.

С:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be 
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
325 frames in 5.0 seconds = 64.892 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.931 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.935 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.933 FPS
```

Без:

```
$ glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
396 frames in 5.0 seconds = 79.072 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.934 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.933 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.934 FPS
```

Может видеокарта не рабочая или ее как-то иначе запускать нужно? Подскажите как ее использовать в Linux?

P.S. Запускал в LiveCD Ubuntu там тоже драйверов не находит

Comment: `Так их нету даже на оф. сайте.` Ты прям уверен в этом? https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsF1.png

Comment: @donRumata я уже пытался, установить, но там вылетают не разрешенные зависимости... да версия для убунту 14.01, а у меня 18.04.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1066106/457538

Comment: @donRumata у меня перестала работать клавиатура и точпад после этого метода